# Using ng-bootstrap in Angular2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular2 with typescript. The dependencies are resolved using npm.

I want to use Modal dialog in my application. For this, I need to include ng-bootstrap in my application. I need to ng-bootstrap modal dialog in my application.

Comment: [ngx-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap) - the result of a single google search.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps in 'Getting Started' here.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started